# secure ajax webservices / webservices proxy

Tags: ajax, web-services, security, proxy, reverse-proxy

i have a webservice which is being consumed by my website using ajax. since im using ajax i cannot have ip restrictions on my webservice. i know i can always add an additional layer of security by using a proxy to call my webservice and the ajax code calls the proxy not the webservice. this way i can always restrict access to my webservice to only allow requests from the proxy

but the end problem is not solved. that is any smart end user can always come to know the proxy url im using from my ajax code and fire requests to this proxy to access all the webservice data

how do i secure my webservice (with or without proxy) such that it only serves requests which come from my website

i can always use http_referrer check in my proxy but thats easy to hack...

is there a fool proof way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can implement this is by using two way SSL authentication for your website.

> In two-way SSL authentication, the SSL
>   client application verifies the
>   identity of the SSL server
>   application, and then the SSL server
>   application verifies the identity of
>   the SSL-client application.
>
> Two-way SSL authentication is also
>   referred to as client authentication
>   because the application acting as an
>   SSL client presents its certificate to
>   the SSL server after the SSL server
>   authenticates itself to the SSL
>   client.

This way before executing any WS request your WS will first check if your client has the valid SSL certificate or not. If it does not then the WS will not execute. Implementing two way SSL requires configuration at both ends and can be slightly complicated to implement. However once setup this is a really secure way to call your webservice and ensure that only authorized clients(who already have the certificate) make those calls. So your AJAX code can make a call to a Servlet which in turn can make the call to this service. This way your service url is also not exposed to the browser.

Comment: when you write: ajax code can make a call to a Servlet - since its ajax the code is visible to end users (website users)... so cant a smart end user call the servlet directly?

Comment: Yes he can call the servlet directly with the parameters he wants. But you can always sanitize the request to prevent SQL injection/XSS attacks. More info - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Mitigation